# How to store images in Objects?

Tags: reactjs, object, react-props

what is the proper way to store a url image in this array?
If i call this.props.cover, I'd like for it to display the image of the link. What would be the proper way to address this?

```js
const ALBUMS = [
  {  id: 1, 
    title: "Lemonade", 
    artist: "Beyoncé", 
    year: 2016 
 cover: img src= "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e9/Massive_Attack_-_Mezzanine.png"
  }
```

Comment: how are you rendering this array?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ganiya/pen/NWxMgbK?editors=0010 used Alex's suggestions and it works

Answer (score 0):

You should store a URL like below and pass the Array as props.

```
const albume = [
  {  id: 1, 
    title: "Lemonade", 
    artist: "Beyoncé", 
    year: 2016 ,
 cover: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e9/Massive_Attack_-_Mezzanine.png"
  }]


const showImgs=(props)=>(props.map((x,key)=>
   <img key={key} alt='' src={x.cover} />
  ))
```

[Look at this sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/store-images-in-objects-s3bhv)

Comment: thanks! I used filter for all the props so I did <h3> {album.title} - {album.artist} - {album.year} </h3>
         <img src={album.cover} />
       </div>

Answer (score 0):

Store the URL normally

```
const ALBUMS = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Lemonade",
        artist: "Beyoncé",
        year: 2016,
        cover: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e9/Massive_Attack_-_Mezzanine.png"
      }
    ]
```

and if you want to use it, you can use it by calling the object.

```
ALBUMS[0].cover
```